# why java.nio.charset.Charsets compile error?

Tags: java, javac

`import java.nio.charset.Charsets` in my class UriCodec.java,but when i use javac(jdk6) compile this class error. for example:
javac UriCodec.java

error code:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charsets;
                       ^
UriCodec.java:140: Can not find symbol
symbol： Variable Charsets
position： class com.android.exchange.utility.UriCodec
        appendEncoded(builder, s, Charsets.UTF_8, false);
                                  ^
UriCodec.java:144: Can not find symbol
symbol： Variable Charsets
position： class com.android.exchange.utility.UriCodec
        appendEncoded(builder, s, Charsets.UTF_8, true);
                                  ^
UriCodec.java:203: Can not find symbol
symbol： Variable Charsets
position： class com.android.exchange.utility.UriCodec
        return decode(s, false, Charsets.UTF_8);
                                ^
UriCodec.java:214: Can not find symbol
symbol： Method toHexString(byte,boolean)
position： class java.lang.Byte
        sb.append(Byte.toHexString(b, true));
                      ^
5 error
```

my class:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.Charsets;
public abstract class UriCodec {


    public final void appendEncoded(StringBuilder builder, String s) {
        appendEncoded(builder, s, Charsets.UTF_8, false);
    }

    public final void appendPartiallyEncoded(StringBuilder builder, String s) {
        appendEncoded(builder, s, Charsets.UTF_8, true);
    }

    public static String decode(String s) {
        return decode(s, false, Charsets.UTF_8);
    }


   public final String encode(String s, Charset charset) {
        // Guess a bit larger for encoded form
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s.length() + 16);
        appendEncoded(builder, s, charset, false);
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give us more information? Some example code where you use this library?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: In future, please don't say that you get an error without telling us *what that error is*. It's like going to the doctor and saying, "I'm not feeling very well, but I'm not going to tell you in what way, or allow you to examine me."

Comment: replace with
java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no such class as `Charsets`. There's [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) (singular) but that's not the same thing...

I suspect you got a message like this:

```
UriCodec.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import java.nio.charset.Charsets;
                       ^
  symbol:   class Charsets
  location: package java.nio.charset
1 error
```

When you get a compiler error, **read it**. If the compiler says it can't find a symbol, then there's usually a very good reason for it - so double-check that you've spelled everything correctly, with the correct casing.

Change your import to

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
```

and all should be well.

... or if you meant a different `Charsets` class (such as [the one in Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html)) you should add an import for *that* class instead.

Comment: i dont think the answer is this simple. java.nio.charset.Charset does not contain members such as "UTF_8" as the example code shows. in fact you can see the use here in some android code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/nfc/NdefRecord.java

Comment: @Sam: I've edited the answer, just adding a bit at the bottom.

Comment: fair enough. I'm personally trying to work out where i can find and import these classes from now.

Comment: also, the NDEfRecord class seems to be a little inconsistent in that you specify at "type" by passing a string, but can get it back as a byte[] - internally converted using Charsets. So there's no real consistent/compatible way of using it nicefully (that's a new word btw)

Comment: Using more recent documentation, should be `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html